# PHP:: three echo statements with the same result

Tags: php

Perhaps this is a petty question, but consider the following PHP code:

```
$a = "foo1"; $b = "foo2"; $c = "foo3";

echo $a, $b, $c;

echo $a . $b . $c;

echo "$a$b$c";
```

aren't these three statements equivalent. What's the difference.
What if one cannot decide whether to use one or the other?

Comment: The third one is incorrect, because you should never mix non-escaped variables inside with regular string. You should always use this syntax: "string" . $a

Comment: @MorganWilde why not? It works just fine and works for a reason. (inb4 so does goto)

Comment: @MorganWilde I believe you misunderstand the purpose of single and double quotes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: @MorganWilde: It's not incorrect, though I agree with you, it is sloppy coding. There is an advantage to the double quotes, however: `$i = 123;` is an int. `"$i";` no echo, nothing but the quotes: $i is now a string. This comes in handy when your code is written (as it should be) with value and type checks all over the place

Comment: @morganwilde: "$a$b$c" is only 'bad' if the statement could be mis-interpreted, e.g. `$a = 'hello'; $x = "$athere"` - there is no variable named `athere`, but `$x = "{$a}there";` works just fine.

Comment: @LachlanPease which can be confusing to read, but is the defined behavior. I certainly do prefer to use {$i} or {$ith} for more readability, but I don't feel that there's anything wrong with `"$a$b$c"`

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. This will definitely improve my understanding of double quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The first one simply echoes out 3 values in a single call. The other two do string concatenations and output the result of that operation. In other words, if you were doing this a few zillion times in a row, the first version would probably be slightly faster, because there's less string operations going on.

That being said, even if you reduce string operations in PHP, the output produced by the echo statements will still be tacked onto the end of an output buffer, and stuffing in a single larger string may be more efficient than multiple smaller strings.

In the grand scheme of things, there'll probably be very little difference between any of those versions, so go with the one that makes the most sense to you, and is easiest for maintenance down the road.

Answer (score 0):

They are mostly equivalent, I would assume that the only real difference would be on performance of how it executes. This may become insignificant or nonexistent if you use a php optimizer.

If I was to guess, I would say that echo #1 is fastest, followed by echo #2, and lastly echo #3.

Why I say this?:

echo #1:
plays directly off of the language construct that it is and simply spits out the variables.

echo #2:
must first concat the strings together and then echo it out

echo #3:
Must first search through the string and replace what it finds with what the variable is. Which would most likely be the most expensive operaion to handle.

**Additional note:**
You should ALWAYS use single quotes when putting strings into variables *unless* you explicitly want variables replaced on the inside. Thus your first line:

```
$a = "foo1"; $b = "foo2"; $c = "foo3";
```

Should be:

```
$a = 'foo1'; $b = 'foo2'; $c = 'foo3';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note about the third method:

When using variables in double quotes, I am in the habit of using curly brackets because they escape array-based variables:

```
echo "{$a}{$b}{$c}";
```

If `$c` were an associative array and you wanted to output some element of it, the statement would then be:

```
echo "{$a}{$b}{$c['foo']}";
```

Sometimes this results in neater string formatting than concatenating variables and strings together for output.